# childthread1 wait until childthread2 complete its execution in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to pause the execution of **t1 (thread_A)** until the **t2 (thread_B)** complete its execution.

```
import threading
import time
def thread_A():
    for x in range(50):
        print(x)
        time.sleep(0.5)

def thread_B():
    for x in range(5):
        print(x)
        time.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=thread_A)
    t1.start()
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=thread_B)
    t2.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, the simplest way:

```
...
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=thread_B)
    t2.start()
    t2.join()  # wait t2 finished
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=thread_A)
    t1.start()
    t1.join()  # wait t1 finished
```

As I know there is no special method to pause a thread. These should be somehow synchronized. For example, using [threading.Event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Event) object:

```
import threading
import time

event = threading.Event()

def thread_A():
    event.wait()
    for x in range(50):
        print(x)
        time.sleep(0.5)

def thread_B():
    for x in range(5):
        print(x)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    event.set()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=thread_A)
    t1.start()
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=thread_B)
    t2.start()
```

Comment: But in this case main thead also wait for the completion of child threads which cause GUI freez.